# Google doc viewer with bytestream

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-document-viewer

I am trying to use google document viewer. Could not find any documentation for this.

If you have a publicly accessible document it works fine.
But all documents are stored as blobs in my mvc app. 
So I am trying to do something like this

```
https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://example.com/mycontroller/myaction?param1=10&userSig=mysignature
```

Controller returns

```
return File(
                <byte array  byte[]>,
                MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet,
                documentResponse.Data.DocumentName);
```

But it's not returning any preview. Want to know is this possible to do? or it only supports publicly accessible file?

Answer (score 0):

Code actually works, issue was it was breaking before hitting return.